# spi_write_then_read with variant register size

Tags: linux, spi

As I understand the term "word length" (spi_bits_per_word) in spi, defines the CS (chip select) active time.
It therefore seems that linux driver will function correctly when dealing with simple spi protocols which keeps word size constant.

But, How can we deal with spi protocols which use different spi size as part of protocol.
for example cs need to be active for sending spi word - 9 bits, and then reading spi - 8 bits or 24 bits (the length of the register read is different each time, depends on register)

How can we implement that using `spi_write_then_read` ?

Do we need to set bits_per_word size for the sending and then another bits_per_word for the receiving ?

Regards,
Ran

Answer (score 1):

"word length" means number of bits you can send in one transaction. It doesn't defines the CS (chip select) active time. You can keep it active for whatever time you want(least is for word-length).
SPI has got some format. You cannot randomly read-write whatever number of bits you want.Most of SPI supports 4-bit, 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit mode. If the given mode doesn't satisfy your requirement then you need to break your requirement. For eg:- To read 24-bit data, we need to use 8-bit word-length transfer for 3 times.
Generally SPI is fullduplex means it will read at same time it will write.

Comment: Thanks, I hink spi also use 9-bits more, in additional , Right ? I'm also not sure what "transaction" means in spi/

Comment: As far as I have worked. I never encountered 9-bit SPI i.e. never seen a hardware supporting 9-bit SPI Tx/Rx. If you need 9-bit SPI you need to bit bang it.Here transaction means number of bits you transmit at a time. For eg:- if I set word-length to be 4, then I can send 4-bit in one transaction.